# Is it acceptable to ask recruiters to fill out an information gathering survey?

Tags: job-search

While I've recently begun looking for a new job, I've been talking with quite a few people (mostly recruiters). Something I thought might be helpful would be to create a short survey the contained a few key questions I usually have for recruiters.

Before sitting down to create such a survey, I figured I'd come and see what others thought about doing something like this.

Keep in mind I'd not ask for them to fill out the survey until after we'd had a short chat or exchanged emails.

Would something like this potentially be too impersonal for something like looking for a job?

Comment: What sort of questions is the survey going to contain? Seems to me you're probably best off just asking them in the initial chat.

Comment: @PhillipKendall Hmm. Thinking about it a little bit I'd say I'd ask questions such as locations they work in, number of potential positions they have to fill, etc. I'd potentially use it to organize contact information such as the agency they work for, phone number, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would something like this potentially be too impersonal for something
>   like looking for a job?

You can ask for anything. And the recruiter can reject you for any reason.

What you are proposing is so far out of the norms, that it's not something I'd suggest attempting if you actually want the job.

Ask a few questions during your chat. Don't get carried away with it. And don't ask them to complete a survey.

Comment: I agree. Unsolicited surveys of this type should only be attempted if the survey is the only agenda or you can force them to be done without repercussions. Neither of which apply in this case.

Comment: If the recruiters also ask us to fill out random stuff, why not? <sarcasm>